# disclose modal gradually, not completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a filter button on my site that opens a modal window. You can filter by four parameters (in the code below, these are FilterMethod, FilterStatusCode, FilterLink, FilterDate). All these four parameters are made in the form of a drop-down list.

My problem is that if I open one of the options for filtering, then the modal window expands immediately to 85% (as indicated in the code). But I would like the modal window to open gradually.

So, If I open one of the parameters for filtering then the height of the modal window is less than 85% which it does not open to the full height at once, but fills gradually.

```
    const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 300,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '1px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
    overflow: 'auto',

};


    export default function ModalWindow() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterMethodExpanded, setIsFilterMethodExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterStatusCodeExpanded, setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterLinkExpanded, setIsFilterLinkExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterDateExpanded, setIsFilterDateExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleOpen}><FilterAltIcon /></Button>
            <Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                disableScrollLock={true}
            >
                <Box sx={style} style={{
                    height: (
                        isFilterMethodExpanded ||
                        isFilterStatusCodeExpanded ||
                        isFilterLinkExpanded ||
                        isFilterDateExpanded) ? '85%' : 'auto'
                }}>
                    <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                        Filters
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterMethod isExpanded={isFilterMethodExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterMethodExpanded}></FilterMethod>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterStatusCode isExpanded={isFilterStatusCodeExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded}></FilterStatusCode>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterLink isExpanded={isFilterLinkExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterLinkExpanded}></FilterLink>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterDate isExpanded={isFilterDateExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterDateExpanded}></FilterDate>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <ApplyCancelButtons setOpen={setOpen} />
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: It looks like CSS transitions might help you there, unless there's something weird going on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i made an error in the previous answer. Replace || with && and it should work.

```
  const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 300,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '1px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4,
    overflow: 'scroll',
    maxHeight: '85%'
};


export default function ModalWindow() {
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [isFilterMethodExpanded, setIsFilterMethodExpanded] = React.useState(false);
const [isFilterStatusCodeExpanded, setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded] = React.useState(false);
const [isFilterLinkExpanded, setIsFilterLinkExpanded] = React.useState(false);
const [isFilterDateExpanded, setIsFilterDateExpanded] = React.useState(false);
const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={handleOpen}><FilterAltIcon /></Button>
        <Modal
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            disableScrollLock={true}
        >
            <Box sx={style} style={{
                height: (
                    isFilterMethodExpanded &&
                    isFilterStatusCodeExpanded &&
                    isFilterLinkExpanded &&
                    isFilterDateExpanded) ? '85%' : 'auto'

            }}>
                <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                    Filters
                </Typography>

                <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                    <FilterMethod isExpanded={isFilterMethodExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterMethodExpanded}></FilterMethod>
                </Typography>

                <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                    <FilterStatusCode isExpanded={isFilterStatusCodeExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded}></FilterStatusCode>
                </Typography>

                <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                    <FilterLink isExpanded={isFilterLinkExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterLinkExpanded}></FilterLink>
                </Typography>
```

Comment: I looked back at my answer and it does have &&. Why did you replace it with || ?

Comment: Yes, it works. But then overflow doesn't work. Modal expands without height limit

Comment: add the required overflow into the condition. Can you give an example of what your overflow looks like?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant. Let me explain: in the case of &&, the overflow starts working when all filters are open (FilterMethod, FilterStatusCode, FilterLink, FilterDate). If at least one of them is closed, then scrolling is not enabled.

Comment: Addition: If I use ||, the scrolling starts properly at 85%. But when you open any of the filtering options, the modal window expands immediately to 85%.

Comment: Is this the desired behavior or what is happening now? You're not very clear yourself. As i said. You can mention the type of overflow in the same condition as the height. If you can attach a video with an explanation that would be great and it would help me detect what you need. thank you

Comment: This is what is happening now. In a couple of minutes, I'll update the condition with a video. Thank you for helping me solve the problem

Comment: i updated my code with a condition for the overflow. Try that and let me know if it's of any help

Comment: I have added a video to my question with your latest code changes. Yes, filter options open, but overflow doesn't work if at least one of the filter options is closed

Comment: Add overflow scroll to the styles and remove the overflow condition. I updated my code. Let me know if this works.I also added a maxHeight condition so your modal never goes over the 85% desired height. Please copy the code and let me know if it's helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the long answer. Yes sir, you are a great programmer, it works

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple calculation based on the amount of opened filters, see example below:

```js
    export default function ModalWindow() {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterMethodExpanded, setIsFilterMethodExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterStatusCodeExpanded, setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterLinkExpanded, setIsFilterLinkExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const [isFilterDateExpanded, setIsFilterDateExpanded] = React.useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

// -- Start --    
    const height = React.useMemo(() => {
        const openedFiltersCount = isFilterMethodExpanded + isFilterStatusCodeExpanded + isFilterLinkExpanded + isFilterDateExpanded;
        return openedFiltersCount ? `${85 / openedFiltersCount}%` : "auto";
      }, [isFilterMethodExpanded, isFilterStatusCodeExpanded, isFilterLinkExpanded, isFilterDateExpanded]);
// -- End --

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleOpen}><FilterAltIcon /></Button>
            <Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                disableScrollLock={true}
            >
                <Box sx={style} style={{
                    height
                }}>
                    <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                        Filters
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterMethod isExpanded={isFilterMethodExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterMethodExpanded}></FilterMethod>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterStatusCode isExpanded={isFilterStatusCodeExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterStatusCodeExpanded}></FilterStatusCode>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterLink isExpanded={isFilterLinkExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterLinkExpanded}></FilterLink>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <FilterDate isExpanded={isFilterDateExpanded} setIsExpanded={setIsFilterDateExpanded}></FilterDate>
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <ApplyCancelButtons setOpen={setOpen} />
                    </Typography>
                </Box>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately it doesn't work. As before, the modal expands to its full height at once.